# Can I develop a personal app for Windows Phone 7 without going through the App Store?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to develop an app for my own use only for Windows Phone 7. Can I do it without going through the app store? As in from my PC straight to the phone using USB?

Comment: Paying $99 will discourage me from getting an WP7 phone and I would look into an Android phone.

Comment: Go the android way, you shouldn't need to pay for something you already paid.

Comment: @alfa64 I don't like Android and I already have another type of OS phone.

Comment: Because of java? Search for basic4android it's great if you already know visual basic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of late 2011, you can unlock your phone for $9 in order to install your own applications: http://www.winrumors.com/windows-phone-chevronwp7-unlock-now-available-homebrew-apps-come-alive/

Comment: Yes I unlocked it with Chevron earlier.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this, up to a limit of 10 apps loaded at a time (presumably per marketplace account).

You need to have an active marketplace subscription to deploy directly to the phone.

Comment: Does this mean I have to pay Microsoft $100/year to put an app on my own phone?

Comment: That is the current state of things. Perhaps they'd consider reviewing this if a suggestion was made in their suggestions forum, but I can understand it not being critical for day one delivery under a fixed time schedule.

Answer (score 2):

No. You are required to have a AppHub account to unlock your device before you can deploy  *any* applications.

An AppHub account is available for Students for **FREE** through the [Microsoft Dreamspark](https://www.dreamspark.com/default.aspx) initiative and $99 USD annual subscription for commercial or individual developers. For more information about AppHub read this [article](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/10/11/introducing-app-hub-for-windows-phone-7-amp-indie-game-developers.aspx).

So you have two options**:

1. register at an education provider, perhaps in an advanced programming or CS unit.
2. pay the USD$99 for the annual subscription and publish your applications to the store either as free or try to recoup the investment of the subscription and your time.

** actually you have three options but I will not discuss the third one here...

Comment: Will the published app be available to public? It's a personal app for my own use only.

Comment: @Tony: It is your choice at the end of the day if you want to publish your app on the marketplace. Regardless, you still need to unlock the phone before you can deploy to the phone.

Answer (score 2):

Enterprise or out-of-market app deployment is not available as part of the [initial release](http://www.windowsitpro.com/blogs/BusinessTechnologyPerspectives/tabid/2812/entryid/72332/Will-Missing-Enterprise-Features-Slow-Windows-Phone-7-Adoption.aspx):

> There won't be the ability [at launch] to distribute applications outside the marketplace," Bigg said. "But we are looking into how we enable other [app deployment] scenarios in the future.

Comment: Even when enterprise or out-of-market app deployment is available, I expect there to be a unlock fee per device or annual subscription that you will have to pay for the privilege.